# Wireless driver on cd not working for ubuntu distribution, but in windows it works fine

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, usb

I have a USB wireless dongle, which is not detected by ubuntu. The drivers that come with the dongle are useless in linux and have major issues with installation. I have tried to install NDISWRAPPER, but the NDISGTK install fails with the error `ndisgtk`. I cannot install through the store as the ethernet port is dead. When i type in `lsusb` in terminal i get:

```
0bda:0179 realtek semiconductor corp
```

- Is there any way to get the dongle working without the need of internet prior to the dongle working. The system I am running is ubuntu 12.04 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your device uses the driver 8188eu. It is certainly possible, although quite difficult, to download the driver, the build tools required to compile the driver and all their dependencies on another computer, transfer them on a USB or CD and install them on the Ubuntu 12.04 computer. You will need this file: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/archive/master.zip

In order to compile the driver, you will need *linux-headers* matching your running kernel; find out with:

```
uname -r
```

For instance, if you find that you have 3.11.0-18-generic, then you need linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic. Find and download the headers and all their dependencies here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ Search for linux-headers matching your kernel version. Be sure to note and download all the package dependencies.

You also need to search for and download *build-essential* and all its dependencies. In some cases, the dependencies may already be installed; check:

```
sudo dpkg -s <some_package>
```

In some cases, the dependencies have their own dependencies that also need to be downloaded.

Once everything is on the USB or CD, copy them to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine. Open a terminal and install them with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If any package fails because a dependency is missing, download it and copy it over and try again. Once everything is installed, right-click the file master.zip and select 'Extract Here.' It will decompress into a folder named rtl8188eu-master. Compile the driver:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8188eu-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

You will have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel only. We need just one more step in order to be able to recompile when a later kernel version is installed. Once you are connected:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

When Update Manager installs a later kernel, after reboot, recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8188eu-master
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Or, you could trade this device for a fully supported plug and play USB.

Comment: thank you very much. I will try this now and see if it works

Comment: the complexity of this is massive, will try to figure it out tomorrow thank you